# Gulp-stylus using jeet error

Tags: gulp, stylus

I'm getting an error when trying to run jeet on stylus with gulp. This is my stylus task:

```
gulp.task('stylus', function(){
    return gulp.src('src/assets/styl/*styl')
        .pipe(stylus(use:[jeet()]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(buildPaths.css))
        .pipe(connect.reload())
});
```

And the error i'm getting:

```
    /var/www/html/eve/gulpfile.js:50  
            .pipe(stylus(use:[jeet()]))  
                         ^^^
    SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
        at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
        at Module._compile (module.js:513:28)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
        at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
        at require (internal/module.js:20:19)  
at Liftoff.handleArguments (/home/eve/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.1/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
    at Liftoff.<anonymous> (/home/eve/.nvm/versions/node/v6.3.1/lib/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/liftoff/index.js:198:16)
```

I've already tried to put jeet() out of the array, like `(use: jeet())` and also checked the syntax a hundred times and it seems there is no ) missing. It only works when I remove the `use: [jeet()]` from code. Anyone has any idea of how to use stylus + jeet with gulp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I´m not sure this is the problem but I think you need braces here: `stylus({use: [jeet()]})`

```
gulp.task('stylus', function(){
    return gulp.src('src/assets/styl/*styl')
        .pipe(stylus({use: [jeet()]}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(buildPaths.css))
        .pipe(connect.reload())
});
```